# How to call .bat from another .bat with input parameters . txt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How to call .bat from another .bat with input parameters  txt
I got args.txt file from source.bat that contains parameter values of source.bat.

```
    args.txt  conatins "E:\DEstination" "E:\SSSS1" "PWD" "UID" "DB_SERVER" "DBNAME"
```

Now I want to call destin.bat using args.txt params .

I tried to call from test.bat like below,

```
    call destin.bat args.txt .
```

but  this way didn't work

```
    set pPath=%~1
    set iPath=%~2
    set DBUserID=%~3
    set DBPassword=%~4
    set DBurl=%~5
    set DBNAME=%~6
```

Please suggest me some other way to call .bat from .bat with .txt inputs .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the arguments into a variable e.g.:

```
set /p args= < args.txt
call destin.bat %args%
```

The /p with set looks for standard input to populate the variable (this would usually be provided by the user). Using the < symbol before the file name redirects data from the file to the standard input (which is then used to set the variable).

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (args.txt) do call destin.bat %%a
```

Read the line and use it as argument to the call